# Possible to mirror texts to a second phone?

Tags: sms, rich-communication-services

Is it possible to use a second phone to send/receive texts via my primary phone?

I would like to mirror all of my texts (including RCS and ideally MMS) to a second phone in my apartment so that when I come home I can put my normal distracting phone away and just keep a barebones phone that can't do much beyond texting and control of home devices (Spotify/Sonos/Hue/etc).  (I know that in theory I can use something like AppBlock but realistically it's more likely that I'll "temporarily" disable the blocks and then get distracted again; I need more friction.)

As far as I can tell there used to be apps like FreeForward that did this, but it doesn't seem to be in the Play store (anymore?).  Is this possible, particularly in a post-RCS world?

Thanks!